# show modal when checkbox is check or uncheck

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

Click here to view my code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Z7QI9Ec53zfkDylnseAc?p=preview

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="album in albums">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="album.selected" value={{album.name}} ng-click="save()"/> {{album.name}}
</li>
```

Script:

```
$scope.save = function(item){
 $scope.mods = item;
  $scope.albumNameArray = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.albums, function(album){
  if (album.selected) $scope.albumNameArray.push(album.name);
  return false;
  });
 };
 $scope.edit = function(){
            if ($scope.albumNameArray ) {
                            $('#showModal').modal('show');
                        } else {
                            $('#showModal2').modal('show');
                        }

          }
```

My project is working fine if I click the save button without checking the checkbox but If I check and then uncheck it, same modal was appearing.
This works fine only in first reload.
I want to make is, if I check the checkbox, ok modal will show else other one modal will show without reloading

Comment: Please provide more information(code).

Comment: thank you for your reply :) heres my plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z7QI9Ec53zfkDylnseAc?p=info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works fine only in first reload.

The reason it's working the first time is because the `$scope.albumNameArray` array is undefined until `$scope.save` is called for the first time.

You should initialize an empty array before `$scope.save` is called, and then check the `length` property of the array in the `if` statement.

Previously, you were just checking whether `$scope.albumNameArray` was defined, which would return true even if the array was empty (which is why you need to check the `length` property to determine if the array contains any values).

[**Updated Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jscONR8QqWACgmYAtNXi?p=preview)

```
$scope.edit = function(){
  if ($scope.albumNameArray.length) {
    $('#showModal').modal('show');
  } else {
    $('#showModal2').modal('show');
  }
}
```